# Draw pattern on a threejs shape

Tags: three.js, textures, shapes

I've been trying without success to draw a shape with a pattern on it with Three.js. So far I got to this point:

```
var s = 0.25;
var sqLength = 80;
var squareShape = new THREE.Shape();
squareShape.moveTo( 0,0 );
squareShape.lineTo( 0, sqLength );
squareShape.lineTo( sqLength, sqLength );
squareShape.lineTo( sqLength, 0 );
squareShape.lineTo( 0, 0 );

var points = shape.createPointsGeometry();
var spacedPoints = shape.createSpacedPointsGeometry( 100 );
var extrudeSettings = { amount: 20, bevelThickness:1 };

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( squareShape, extrudeSettings );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/oak.jpg' )
  });

var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ material ] );
mesh.position.set( x, y, z - 75 );
mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );
mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
group.add( mesh );
```

But the final render only draws the shape with a similar color to the pattern, but not the pattern itself. I've looked everywhere with no luck. With a 3D figure (such as a cube) it can be done relatively easy, but not on a 2D figure. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the texture show up if you set `sqLength` to 1?